# Sass mixin and include not working

Tags: css, include, sass, mixins

I am using the basic example of the mixin and include, but I can't get it to work.

This is the code I am using.

```
    @mixin border-radius($radius) {
  -webkit-border-radius: $radius;
     -moz-border-radius: $radius;
      -ms-border-radius: $radius;
          border-radius: $radius;
} 

    .test {
    @include border-radius(10px);
    padding: 20px;
    background: red;
    font-size: 12px;

    h2 {
        font-size: 24px;
        color: yellow;
    }
    p {
        color: #333333;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to work for me:

http://jsfiddle.net/lee_gladding/twvsdsnt/

Take a look, there could be another problem causing you not to see what you are expecting.

Im guessing you have added the class `test` to an element?

Comment: i think sass is not working on my system cause the h2 and p css is also not showing. can u tell me how can i check its working or not?

Comment: like pastorello says below, you have to compile sass into css in order to use it in a browser page. Firstly have you installed SASS? http://sass-lang.com/install

Comment: I would use compass to do the watching and compiling for you: http://thesassway.com/beginner/getting-started-with-sass-and-compass

Comment: You can also edit the config.rb file to select your source and destination folders, keeping your sass and css separate. note that any files in the sass directory will be compiled into css, however file names beginning with an underscore are not compiled down to css, these files are used as includes to help build projects with a modular approach.

Comment: now i am getting this error 'Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/plain: "file:///C:/sass-test/sass/style.scss".'

Answer (score 0):

Code is ok, 
did you compile your scss file?
JSFiddle automatically compile sass but, in normal situations, you have to compile it and obtain a .css file in order to use it on a website.

check zurb foundation docs for sass compiling, it's very simple and clean:
http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/sass.html

or you can just play with online resources like this:
http://sassmeister.com/